# Django - Saving and Updating formset with inline

Tags: python, django, formset, inline-formset

I have a TestingQuestion and TestingQuestionOption classes. 
When creating TestingQuestions I make use of stackedinline to create TestingQuestionOption's as well.
At the moment creating new TestingQuestion along with TestingQuestionOptions works. 
The problem I'm having is when I want to save the TestingQuestion I have already created. ie try edit it and save the changes.
I get "list index out of range" error on this line

```
 "question = saved_options[0].question"
```

which is in the "save_existing_objects" method under "TestingQuestionFormSet" class

```
saved_options = super(TestingQuestionFormSet, self).save_new_objects(commit)
```

returns None and I'm not sure why, as I'm expecting it to return the TestingQuestionOption's.
Any help will be greatly apprecaited. Thanks

Here's the code

models.py

```
class TestingQuestion(models.Model):

class TestingQuestionOption(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(TestingQuestion, null=True, blank=False)
```

admin.py

```
class TestingQuestionOptionInline(admin.StackedInline, SummernoteInlineModelAdmin):
    model = TestingQuestionOption
    formset = TestingQuestionFormSet

class TestingQuestionAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin, ImportExportModelAdmin):
    form = TestingQuestionCreateForm
    inlines = (TestingQuestionOptionInline,)
```

forms.py

```
class TestingQuestionFormSet(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):

    def save_new_objects(self, commit=True):
        saved_options = super(TestingQuestionFormSet, self).save_new_objects(commit)
        if commit:
            question = saved_options[0].question
            for option in saved_options:
                if option.order == 0:
                    option.order = TestingQuestionOption.objects.filter(question=question).count() + 1
                if option.name == "Auto Generated":
                    option.name = "%s Option %s" % (question, option.order)
                option.save()

            if len(saved_options) < 2:
                order = TestingQuestionOption.objects.filter(question=question).count() + 1
                name = "%s Option %s" % (question, order)
                TestingQuestionOption.objects.create(name=name, order=order, question=question, correct=False)
        return saved_options

    def save_existing_objects(self, commit=True):
        saved_options = super(TestingQuestionFormSet, self).save_existing_objects(commit)
        if commit:
            question = saved_options[0].question
            for option in saved_options:
                if option.order == 0:
                    option.order = TestingQuestionOption.objects.filter(question=question).count() + 1
                if option.name == "Auto Generated":
                    option.name = "%s Option %s" % (question, option.order)
                option.save()

            if len(saved_options) < 2:
                order = TestingQuestionOption.objects.filter(question=question).count() + 1
                name = "%s Option %s" % (question, order)
                TestingQuestionOption.objects.create(name=name, order=order, question=question, correct=False)
        return saved_options

class TestingQuestionCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def save(self, commit=True):
        testing_question = super(TestingQuestionCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if testing_question.order == 0 or testing_question.name == "Auto Generated":
            count = TestingQuestion.objects.filter(module__id=self.data.get("module")).count() + 1
            module = Module.objects.get(id=self.data.get("module"))
            name = "%s Question %d" % (module, count)
            while TestingQuestion.objects.filter(name=name):
                count += 1
                name = "%s Question %d" % (module, count)
            testing_question.name = name
            testing_question.order = count
        testing_question.save()

        question_content = self.cleaned_data.get("question_content")
        testing_question.question_content = process_mathml_content(question_content, 0, testing_question.id)

        answer_content = self.cleaned_data.get("answer_content")
        testing_question.answer_content = process_mathml_content(answer_content, 1, testing_question.id)

        testing_question.save()

        return testing_question

    class Meta:
        model = TestingQuestion
```